# Community User not being able to edit and save case

Tags: community, case, permissions, button, licenses

User with a community license is able to see cases, and edit them, but Salesforce only shows two options when saving: "Save and New" or "Save and Close", but what if my user wants to just edit the case and save it? Without creating a new one or closing the existing one.

Comment: what component are you using. as far as I am concerned, the standard record details component has an edit option (at least in lightning communities)

Comment: I'm using the Visualforce template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reached to support and they told me that the "Submit" button is the equivalent of "Save" in this situation.